# 173 ошибки в новом пустом проекте

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Здрастуйте, я сейчас учусь по книге `ASP.NET Core MVC 2 с примерами на С#`. И стоило мне соpдать пустой asp.net проект на .net 2.1, мне вылезло это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видите на примере `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` библиотека присуствует в зависимостях. Это случилось после того, как мне пришлось сделать бекап винды на версию месячной давности.

Comment: Sdk стоит? Версия фреймворка? Либы с target sdk совпадают?

Comment: Может стоит создать проект под .net посвежее? Например .NET 6.

Comment: @aepot так как у меня книга по версии .net 2, то я использую данную версию, до отката проблем с этой версией небыло.

Comment: Ничего страшного, если вы практику будете выполнять на свежей версии. Там разница не огромная, все равно вы не будете писать рабочий сервер под устаревший дотнет, верно? Основополагающие штуки типа MVC во всех версиях одинаковые.

Comment: @tym32167 До бекапа, все работало. У меня сейчас .net core 2.1, .net core 3.1, .net 5, .net 6.  А как проверить sdk я не знаю.

Comment: Кстати, .NET Core 2.1 уже давно снят с поддержки и скорее всего у вас не установлен. Ну если боитесь большой разницы с .NET 6, то пишите хотя-бы под 3.1.

Comment: @aepot он у меня установлен, и я уже сделал один проект по учебнику и всё работало отлично.

Comment: @aepot Я сделал пустой проект на .net 6 и там настолько, всё сильно различается, что я не знаю, что менять, стобы было так, как в учебнике, Но там ошибок нету.